# react-pdf slow rendering when using scale prop in Page component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, react-pdf

I am making a pdf viewer using react app. I have a pdf with almost 150 pages and I am using zoom-in and zoom-out icons, I am using `scale` prop in `Page` component to accomplish that. But whenever I zoom-in or zoom-out there is a slight delay in pdf file to re-render with zoomed pages. And that delay doesnt happen for small pdf.
Here is my code -

```
    const [pages, setPages] = React.useState(0);
    const [pagesArr, setPagesArr] = React.useState([]);
    const [scrolledValue, setScrolledValue] = React.useState(0);
    const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = React.useState(1);
    const [pdfScale, setPdfScale] = React.useState(1.0);

    function onLoadSuccess(param) {
        setPages(param.numPages);
        const numArr = [];
        for (let num = 1; num <= param.numPages; num++) {
            numArr.push(num);
        }
        setPagesArr(numArr);
    }

    function handleZoominIcon() {
        setPdfScale(prev => {
            if (prev > 2.1) {
                return 2.2;
            } else {
                return prev + 0.1;
            }
        });
    }

    function handleZoomoutIcon() {
        setPdfScale(prev => {
            console.log(prev);
            if (prev <= 0.5) {
                return 0.5;
            } else {
                return prev - 0.1;
            }
        });
    }


return (
  <section className = 'ppt-view-pdf' style = {scrolledStyle[1], {zoom: '100%'}} ref = {props.pdfViewRef}>
      <Document  file = {PPT} onLoadSuccess = {onLoadSuccess}>
          {pagesArr.map(element => <Page scale = {pdfScale} key = {element} pageNumber = {element}></Page>)}
       </Document>
  </section>
)
```

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The performance was poor because changing the scale factor will re-render all pages. I solved it using `react-window` that virtualises the invisible components in the dom. I used `VariableSizeList` because it was more performant than `FixedSizeList`. Here is a minimal example:

```
import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Document, Page } from "react-pdf/dist/esm/entry.webpack";
import { VariableSizeList } from "react-window";

const PDFDoc = () => {
  const [scale, setScale] = useState(1);
  const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(0);
  const docRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [docWidth, setDocWidth] = useState(0);
  const [docHeight, setDocHeight] = useState(0);

  const onDocumentLoadSuccess = ({ numPages }: { numPages: number }) => {
    setNumPages(numPages);
    const rect = docRef.current?.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (rect) {
      setDocWidth(rect.width);
      setDocHeight(rect.height);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div ref={docRef}>
      {/* TODO: add your zoom controls here */}
      <Document file={"sample.pdf"} onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}>
        <VariableSizeList
          width={docWidth}
          height={docHeight}
          itemCount={numPages}
          estimatedItemSize={numPages}
          itemSize={() => scale * docWidth}
        >
          {({ style, index }) => {
            const currPage = index + 1;

            return (
              <div style={style}>
                <Page scale={scale} pageNumber={currPage} />
              </div>
            );
          }}
        </VariableSizeList>
      </Document>
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can install `react-window` [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window).

## Update

Due to some UI issues with `react-window`, I decided to switch to [react-pdf-viewer](https://github.com/react-pdf-viewer/react-pdf-viewer/) at the end. It's working pretty well for me so far.